# ¿Qué significa “No estaba muy bien con [...]” en la descripción de Don Quijote?

Tags: significado, adverbios, literatura

> Con estas razones perdía el pobre caballero el juicio, y desvelábase por entenderlas y desentrañarles el sentido, que no se lo sacara ni las entendiera el mesmo Aristóteles, si resucitara para sólo ello. No estaba muy [bien](https://es.wiktionary.org/wiki/bien) con las heridas que don Belianís daba y recebía, porque se imaginaba que, por grandes maestros que le hubiesen curado, no dejaría de tener el rostro y todo el cuerpo lleno de cicatrices y señales.

¿Qué significa *estar bien con algo* en la descripción del capítulo primero de *[El ingenioso hidalgo don Quijote de la Mancha](https://www.gutenberg.org/cache/epub/2000/pg2000-images.html#id_1_primero)*?

Answer (score 1):

En la descripción del capítulo primero de El ingenioso hidalgo Don Quijote de la Mancha, la frase "**No estaba muy bien con las heridas que Don Belianís daba y recebía**" significa que el protagonista no estaba a gusto con la cantidad de heridas que el personaje de Don Belianís recibía y daba en la novela que estaba leyendo. Don Quijote estaba preocupado por el hecho de que, a pesar de que los grandes maestros hubieran curado las heridas de Don Belianís, su cuerpo quedaría lleno de cicatrices y señales.

Por tanto, la expresión "**estar bien con algo**" en este contexto significa estar satisfecho o a gusto con algo, mientras que "**no estar muy bien con algo**" significa no estar satisfecho o no estar a gusto con algo.

Answer (score 0):

I would have translated that as *he was not happy with the wounds which*. It seems rather ironic but without the extended context around it it is hard to be sure.